# Cheerio, deleting values between tags

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I have a html like this:

```
<strong>delete1</strong> : 
16X<br>
<strong>delete2</strong> 
: 16X<br>
<strong>delete3</strong>
```

Need to delete tags, and all text between tags. How to do it?
Node.js + cheerio, web scraping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [remove](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#remove-selector-) method in manipulation features of Cheerio.
So you could remove all elements in this content, then you will get only text without any child elements and their texts.

Here is a snippet for example to do this with JQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $elm = $('#demo-container');

  // Remove all child elements then their contents will be gone.
  $elm.find('*').remove();
  console.log('Contents without child elements',$elm.html());

  // Beyond that you could split text with colon and get each values
  console.log('Each line as array',$elm.html().replace(/\s/g, '').split(':'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo-container">
  <strong>delete1</strong> : 
  16X<br>
  <strong>delete2</strong> 
  : 16X<br>
  <strong>delete3</strong>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **cheerio** to **get** the HTML of the parent and remove the unnecessary content with `replace`.

You can also use [X-ray](https://www.npmjs.com/package/x-ray) and use the filters option.